# Handling large amount of traits and properties in classes

Tags: php, laravel

I've got an open-source project that I've been working on for a while, and I'm looking for advice on handling large classes. It's a Laravel 10+ package for building forms, and everything works fine, but every time I look at these field classes, I feel like there could be a better way or that I might be doing this inefficiently.

This package couples with a frontend package that is also open source (utilising Vue3 & Vuetify) to load the forms; this is partly why there are many attributes, as Vuetify offers many options in their fields.

Below is an example of the `AutoCompleteField`. In my next update, I'd like to do a big cleanup and start implementing some better structure, so condensing the files down like so is on the list:

**Current Setup:**

```
<?php

namespace PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Fields;

use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Base\EasyField;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasAnyField;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasAutoSelectFirst;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasChips;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasClosableChips;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasCloseText;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasCounter;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasDirection;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasFilterKeys;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasFilterMode;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasHideNoData;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasHideSelected;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemChildren;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemColor;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemId;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemProps;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItems;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemTitle;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemValue;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasLoadable;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasMenu;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasMultiple;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasNoDataText;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasNoFilter;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasOpenOnClear;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasOpenText;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasReturnObject;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasSearch;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasTransition;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Creatable;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Transformable;

/**
 * Represents an autocomplete field in a form.
 *
 * @extends EasyField
 */
class AutoCompleteField extends EasyField
{
    use Creatable;
    use HasAnyField;
    use HasAutoSelectFirst;
    use HasChips;
    use HasClosableChips;
    use HasCloseText;
    use HasCounter;
    use HasDirection;
    use HasFilterKeys;
    use HasFilterMode;
    use HasHideNoData;
    use HasHideSelected;
    use HasItemChildren;
    use HasItemColor;
    use HasItemId;
    use HasItemProps;
    use HasItems;
    use HasItemTitle;
    use HasItemValue;
    use HasLoadable;
    use HasMenu;
    use HasMultiple;
    use HasNoDataText;
    use HasNoFilter;
    use HasOpenOnClear;
    use HasOpenText;
    use HasReturnObject;
    use HasSearch;
    use HasTransition;
    use Transformable;

    protected string $component = 'v-autocomplete';

    protected string $discriminator = 'AutoCompleteField';

    protected string $type = 'text';
}
```

**Potential Update**

```
<?php

namespace PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Fields;

/**
 * Represents an autocomplete field in a form.
 *
 * @extends \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Base\EasyField
 */
class AutoCompleteField extends \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Base\EasyField
{
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Creatable;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasAnyField;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasAutoSelectFirst;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasChips;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasClosableChips;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasCloseText;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasCounter;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasDirection;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasFilterKeys;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasFilterMode;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasHideNoData;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasHideSelected;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemChildren;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemColor;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemId;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemProps;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItems;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemTitle;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasItemValue;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasLoadable;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasMenu;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasMultiple;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasNoDataText;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasNoFilter;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasOpenOnClear;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasOpenText;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasReturnObject;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasSearch;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\HasTransition;
    use \PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Transformable;

    protected string $component = 'v-autocomplete';

    protected string $discriminator = 'AutoCompleteField';

    protected string $type = 'text';
}
```

**Example of Attribute:**

```
<?php

namespace PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes;

trait HasAnyField
{
    protected bool $any_field = false;

    public function getAnyField(): bool
    {
        return $this->any_field;
    }

    public function setAnyField(bool $any_field): self
    {
        $this->any_field = $any_field;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The reason these all have setters is to try and keep it chainable. Should I update these attributes to be public and then remove the getters? (keep setters so they are still chainable?)

Any other ideas on improving and making some updates would be much appreciated. If anyone has the time (or will), I'd love another set of eyes to review the full project structure at some point as well.

**Additional Info:**

- I've already split common properties that are found among all components, and these reside in the parent class: `PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Base\EasyField`
- I've coupled some attributes that are only required with each other

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reduce redundancy and increase maintainability, you can make the following improvements:

1. Group related traits to reduce the number of use statements and organize your code better.
2. If all traits in a category (like items) are used together frequently, combine them into a single trait.
3. Consider using inheritance or a base class with the main properties and methods shared across different form fields.

Here's an example of how you might start to restructure the code for more efficiency:

```php
namespace PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Fields;

use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Base\EasyField;
use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\FormFieldTraits; // This would be a new trait encapsulating several common traits.

/**
 * Represents an autocomplete field in a form.
 *
 * @extends EasyField
 */
class AutoCompleteField extends EasyField
{
    use FormFieldTraits; // Include the new combined trait.

    protected string $component = 'v-autocomplete';
    protected string $discriminator = 'AutoCompleteField';
    protected string $type = 'text';
}
```

Step 2: Adjust the Written Code to Reflect Structural Changes

Let's adjust the traits section by combining related traits into a new composite trait. An example composite trait might look like this:

```php
namespace PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits;

use PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes\{HasItems, HasItemValue, HasItemTitle, ...}; // and so on

trait FormFieldTraits
{
    use HasItems, HasItemValue, HasItemTitle, ...; // Import all relevant item-related traits.
}
```

Step 3: Write a Clear Example of an Attribute

An example attribute trait, following our optimized structure, could look like this:

```php
namespace PlusTimeIT\EasyForms\Traits\Attributes;

trait HasItems
{
    protected array $items = [];
    
    public function getItems(): array
    {
        return $this->items;
    }
    
    public function setItems(array $items): self
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In this example, `HasItems` might be one of the several traits consolidated into the `FormFieldTraits` composite trait if it makes sense based on how `AutoCompleteField` and other field classes are used within the application.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are correct that removing the redundancies will make it a lot cleaner. I'm currently using base classes as much as I can, I just didn't want to post too much code here.